Is there a way to find the exception raised without running the code or using try except(for theory exams)?
Hello i am a high school student just wanted to know the best way of predicting the error by just looking at the code without using try or except . I am asking this for my school theory exam so please reply if you have any suggestions...
just sending this code for an example:
int('str')
by looking at this code i was mistaken that this is a type error but later i understood it was a value error.
So if u do have any way of understanding the error by just looking at the code please let me know ....

In general code - no way, you can only rely on guessing. However with the standard Python exceptions (not customly written exceptions), you can study the official documentation, which states which exceptions are thrown when. https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html

Note that it can't be a TypeError, because int('3') is legal.
